# What file can throttle my network connection on my ISP's behalf?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking

Please help me, this is important.

I am born a Chinese but I am very open-minded and follow the western philosophy. In authoritarian China there is this infamous Great Firewall of China which slows down access to foreign websites and outright blocks many websites (Google, YouTube, DeviantArt, even Wikipedia, to name a few), making accessing unbiased free information basically impossible.

Therefore I use VPNs to access the free internet, and my ISP really wants to cut off my VPN connection. They throttle my VPN connection speed and disconnect my VPN connection frequently. I wrote a Python script that runs 24/7 to combat this, they always lose but they just don't give up.

But recently they are winning, my methods no longer work somehow. The problem is very simple, whenever I connect to VPNs, my connection speed is throttled to a few hundred Kibibytes download and upload, making VPNs useless and basically impossible to browse the internet while connected to VPNs.

I have already disabled TR069 on my modem a long time ago, I have changed the modem's password and changed many other settings, so that there is no backdoor for them to control it. And they also tried to throttle my connection before, I found that it can be fixed by disconnecting WAN (my router's PPPoE connection) and reconnecting WAN.

This time though, my tricks don't work. I thought at first they must somehow opened some backdoor to my modem that I am unaware of, so I changed the modem. I bought a modem via the internet, the modem doesn't have any information added by the internet service providers and all settings are factory default, so there must be no backdoor.

I setup the modem and established the internet WAN connection. But when I connected to the VPN again, the connections are still throttled. I thought this to be impossible, I thought that they must have access to my modem to control my network connection. But now I am proven wrong, so they can control my network without needing to access my modem somehow.

I tried to reset the router (I bought it, it isn't provided by the ISP), no, it is of no use. I tried to reset my computer's internet settings using the following commands and reboot the computer:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
devcon disable *dev_8168*
devcon enable *dev_8168*
start-sleep -seconds 3
netsh winsock reset
netsh winhttp reset proxy
netsh http flush log buffer
net start dot3svc
netsh lan reconnect
net stop dot3svc
netsh interface ip reset
netsh interface ipv4 reset
netsh interface ipv6 reset
netsh interface httpstunnel reset
netsh interface portproxy reset
netsh interface tcp reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /all
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /renew
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{Tab}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(" ")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("R")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("C")
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name AutoDetect -Type DWord -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name AutoDetect -Type DWord -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel" -Name Autoconfig -Type DWord -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name AutoConfigURL -Type String -Value ""
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" -Name AllowRemoteRPC -Type DWord -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" -Name fDenyTSConnections -Type DWord -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name fDenyTSConnections -Type DWord -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Remote Assistance" -Name fAllowFullControl -Type DWord -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Remote Assistance" -Name fAllowToGetHelp -Type DWord -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name fAllowToGetHelp -Type DWord -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name fAllowUnsolicited -Type DWord -Value 0
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles firewallpolicy blockinboundalways,allowoutbound
netsh advFirewall firewall add rule name="Disable Incoming PING IPv6" protocol=icmpv6:8,any dir=in action=block
netsh advFirewall firewall add rule name="Disable Incoming PING IPv4" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=block
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp" -Name TcpAutotuning -Type DWord -Value 1
netsh http flush logbuffer
netsh winhttp reset autoproxy
netsh interface udp reset
netsh branchcache reset
netsh branchcache flush
netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```

It also is useless, my connection is still throttled. So the problem isn't the modem, or the router, or the computer. At this point I am out of ideas and about to give up, my ISP had won, I need to change ISP...

But on another thought, I had thought of another cause, what if my OS was the problem? What if my ISP managed to infect my computer with some virus somehow that gives them advantages? This seemed highly unlikely, but after excluding all possibilities, whatever remains, no matter how counterintuitive, must be correct. This was worthy of investigation, so I gave it a shot, and...

***JACKPOT!*** My computer has multiple permanent storage devices, and I have installed Windows 10 on two of the disks. They are both bootable, but previously I mainly used one OS. So I restarted my computer and booted the other OS, and I connected to the VPN, and I found that my connection isn't throttled. How can this happen if I haven't changed my modem's or my router's settings?

I rebooted my computer and booted the other OS again, connected to the VPN and my connection is throttled, which isn't surprising. But I rebooted again into the OS I didn't use, not throttled. Rebooted again and my VPN is throttled...

So this confirms my hypothesis that the throttling must be correlated to the OS somehow, and the logical conclusion is that my main OS is infected by some script from my ISP that throttles my VPN connection.

But how? I have tried to uninstall the VPN client and reinstall it, no effect. But I did find something very strange, after rebooting, in my main OS's network & internet settings section in the Settings app, under the proxy tab, the checkbox for automatically detect settings is on, it shouldn't be possible, since I have disabled it via my script.

And in Chrome's status bar, sometimes I can see "downloading proxy script" message, which again should be impossible since I have disabled proxy auto-configuration. I opened chrome://net-internals/#proxy and found nothing, `netsh winhttp show proxy` says `"Direct access (no proxy server)."`. But there must be some script that was downloaded and is causing the problems.

I tried to Google search "where is proxy script downloaded to" but I found absolutely nothing useful. So there must be some script that runs when the computer boots and enables proxy automatic configuration and downloads the proxy script and causes the problem, but I have opened Sysinternals Autoruns, and still found nothing.

But I did find something fishy, at system startup there is a process with Windows services icon, without process name, whose command line is `svchost -k networkservice -p`.

So what exactly is the file that is causing the problem? I will of course reinstall the operating system, but knowing the cause can help preventing this from happening again.

Comment: There's a windows update for both Windows 10 and Windows 11 that severely bottlenecks VPN connections. Its a bug in the update, but I have a feeling this is what you're experiencing.

Comment: Who downvoted this question ***FOUR*** days after it was last modified?!! It most certainly isn't on the front page. So whoever downvoted this visited my profile and downvoted to attack me. I was personally targeted. There is no justifiable reason to downvote whatsoever.

Comment: You are mistaken. When I came to this question, it was already downvoted, so I upvoted it because I thought it was not necessary. That happened 4 days ago, and there is only one downvote.

Comment: Hmm.. According to the activity log, the downvote that was placed before I upvoted it has been removed. Possibly that user is deleted. I bet the downvote was placed to correct the user delete.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, it was me, not my ISP. The problem was caused by setting `netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled`, possibly while `Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp" -Name TcpAutotuning -Type DWord -Value 1` has its effect.

So it seems while TCP autotuning level is disabled and autotuning is enabled in the registry, it causes a conflict somehow and slows down VPN connection.

I in my effort to combat my ISP's disruptions changed something I didn't really understand and brought this to myself. It is easy for me to blame my ISP, and I have never considered the possibility that I caused it myself.

I have just run my script on the working OS and VPN connections are immediately slowed. I inspected the commands one by one and then determined that `netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled` must be the cause.

I then run the following command `netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=experimental` and my VPN connections are not throttled again. I set autotuninglevel to disabled and my VPN connections are throttled again...

So I was unwittingly helping my ISP. I set `netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=experimental` and the problem was solved.